# Combine to output value ina query

Tags: mysql, sql

how can Combine to output values. i have my Query below which 3 values under `It.Finance`...suppose high, medium and low..i want to combine medium and low together as average that means my output values could be

high

average(for medium and low)

```
select  count(h.Dept_id) as DeptCount,

i.Id as CompanyId,

i.Account as AccountTotal,

i.Technology as IT,

ISNULL(it.Finance,'NoCapacity') as School

from Institution i left join 

 History h on h.Institution_id = i.Id left join 

   xxxxx

   yyyyy      

group by i.Id,i.Account,i.Technology,it.Finance
```

is it possible?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific with the explanation, or rather show us the table schema with some sample data and expected output based on that.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Best blind guess:***

```
select  count(h.Dept_id) as DeptCount,
i.Id as CompanyId,
i.Account as AccountTotal,
i.Technology as IT,
coalesce(it.Finance,'NoCapacity') as School,
Max(it.Finance) as High, 
(Avg(it.Finance) + Min(it.Finance))/2 as Average
from Institution i left join 
History h on h.Institution_id = i.Id left join 
   xxxxx -- your unknown tables
   yyyyy -- your unknown tables     
group by i.Id, i.Account
```

Comment: @bonCodigo.thanks for your reply.its not to calculate the average value it just to combine medium and low values into one name Average ...